# Installing datamapper mysql dm-mysql-adapter on redhat

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm trying to move a small Sinatra app I have going on an Ubuntu box to a redhat box.

While installing gems, I get a "Can't build native extension" error while trying to install the gem dm-mysql-adapter.

I have mysql-devel installed, which I believe is the required library, but it doesn't seem to work.

All the info I can find online is for Ubuntu and says installing libmysqlclient-dev (which doesn't exist for Redhat; again, I believe mysql-devel is the appropriate package).

Any advice for someone using redhat?

Answer (score 0):

you have the correct package "mysql-devel-5.1.48-1" but the gem installs fine on my centos5 box without the package installed, you could try the ruby-mysql gem instead.

```
[11:13:01][root@HOST:~]# gem search mysql

*** LOCAL GEMS ***


[11:13:03][root@HOST:~]# rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.4


[11:13:11][root@HOST:~]# gem install mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...
...
[11:13:22][root@HOST:~]#
```